# How to javascript create div with sequential name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I got this code to add dynamic input on screen.
I need to solve input names
Known problems:
All **input names** are the same: **supplierproduct1**
When I remove an input it just remove the first input and not the input selected

HTML

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-info-sign"></i> </span>
        <h5>Produtos</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="optionBox">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="widget-content nopadding" id="block">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nome do produto</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="140" name="supplierproduct1" id="supplierproduct1"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="add btn btn-success"> Adicionar produto </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block" id="block"><div class="widget-content nopadding"><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Nome do produto</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" maxlength="140" name="supplierproduct1" id="supplierproduct1">  <span class="remove btn btn-danger"> Excluir </span>  </div></div></div></div>');
});
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
    $("#block").remove();
});
```

I'm sorry guys, I am doing a system to help my store but I'm still learning this stuffs so I can't do it alone, already searched but couldn't do anything using examples a saw around.
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Solution:
html

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-info-sign"></i> </span>
        <h5>Produtos</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="optionBox">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="widget-content nopadding" id="block">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nome do produto</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="140" name="supplierproduct[]" id="supplierproduct[]"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="add btn btn-success"> Adicionar produto </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('.block:last').after(' <div class="block" id="block"><div class="widget-content nopadding"><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Nome do produto</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" maxlength="140" name="supplierproduct[]" id="supplierproduct[]">  <span class="remove btn btn-danger"> Excluir </span> </div></div></div></div>');
});
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).closest('.block').remove();
});
```

Comment: You are not using any [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php)  here

Comment: I know, i need to solve the name first, javascript should create dynamic input names but i dont know how. After this i must add in php

Comment: Your question and title is different from what you need

Comment: Edited, sorry bro

Comment: It will always be the same because the class name is static and you are not doing anything to change it every time you click the button

Comment: Why do you need different names? If you have a repeating set of "supplierproduct" fields they can all have the same name, then in your server-side code you treat the data as an array. (I'm not a PHP guy, but I believe the PHP technique for this is in your HTML say `name="supplierproduct[]"`.) Regarding the problem with the `.remove` button, in the event handler don't use an element ID, select the element to be removed using DOM navigation methods to find the element relative to `$(this)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I found this $(this).closest('.block').remove(); and now remove is working. Thanks. About names I'm still searching for it

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you so much. I edited main post with solution!

Comment: @Lucas, avoid solution in the question. Please create own answer and mark one as accepted to close the topic.